# Closing JDialog Java

Tags: java, swing, dialog, joptionpane

How can I stop dialog box running?

```
String menuInput = null;
        JOptionPane askOpenOrNew = new JOptionPane(
                "Would you like to Open a save\nor create a New world?");
        Object[] askOptions = new String[] { "Open World", "New World",
                "Cancel" };
        askOpenOrNew.setOptions(askOptions);
        JDialog askDialog = askOpenOrNew.createDialog(new JFrame(),
                "There is no World");
        askDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        askDialog.setVisible(true);
```

It keeps the console in Eclipse running after the program, should have, terminated.

EDIT: The dialog box does close (In that it disappears from screen) but the console doesn't terminate unless explicitly told (System.exit(0)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the program to exit, I'd recommend explicitly calling `System.exit(0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to exit after you close the dialog box, you replace

```
askDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

With

```
askDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: EXIT causes an error 'defaultCloseOperation must be one of: DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, HIDE_ON_CLOSE, or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE'